# Python Regular Expressions matching Email

Tags: python, regex

My question is to write a function that, given an email address (a), returns (user, domain) corresponding to the user name and domain name.
given bob@aus.space.com it should return (bob, aus.space.com).

The function should only match if it meets these following

A domain name must end with an alphabetic character. 
Alphabetic characters may be uppercase or lowercase.
No whitespace characters are allowed.

Below is my current code and I am getting invalid syntax errors. Any insight on how to do this easier or cleaner would be much appreciated.

```
import re
def find_email (s):
  re_pattern = (r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0- 9-.]+$)")
  regular_expression_object = re.compile(re_pattern)
  match_object = regular_expression_object.match(s)
  if match_object != None:
    return (match_object.match(s).group('user'),match_object(s).group('domain'))
  else:
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: Hi, shouldn't you have another ")" at the end of return statement? Also, isn't it `match_object != None`? The second part seems to be on the next line for some reason. Also could you give traceback of the error?

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's because of the copy/paste... But it doesn't surprise me that you have a `SyntaxError`. Try to indent your code (this is mandator in python). Remove the stuff that are not correct expressions (like `!= None`) and so...

Comment: Also you didn't name, nor made 2 groups in re_pattern - that also can be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this code would be what you are looking for:

```
import re
def find_email (s):
    re_pattern = (r"(?P<user>^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+)@(?P<domain>[a-zA-Z0-9-._]+[a-zA-Z])$")
    regular_expression_object = re.compile(re_pattern)
    match_object = regular_expression_object.match(s)
    if match_object != None:
        return (match_object.group('user'), match_object.group('domain'))
    else:
        raise ValueError

[In]: find_email("user@email.domain.com")
[Out]: ('user', 'email.domain.com')
```

If you already made match of object you don't need to call "match" on it again - it already has groups.

Also its good practice to use some kind of regex-helping sites - there are multiple of them, such as regex101 for example.

Edit: Ok changed it up a little.

Since first character MUST be alphabetic, its `[a-zA-Z]` to check for it, followed by `[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]` with `+` meaning 1 or more (can change it to `*` if you want 1-letter usernames) of alphanumeric characters plus those few special characters you gave in the original post.

After `@`, `[a-zA-Z0-9-._]+` means 1 or more of characters in this bracket, followed by `[a-zA-Z]` forcing the end of the line - `$` to end with alphabetic character.

If you have still some mails that won't work - check some regex pages for this, with little tinkering it will work.

Comment: I am still having some issues getting the code to past with your adjustments. I think it's an issue with the following rules...."username must be alphabetic character, followed by any number of alphanumeric characters or any of the following special characters" and "A domain name must end with an alphabetic character. It may consist of any of the following characters: alphanumeric characters, . (period), - (hyphen), or _ (underscore)". for the first one I tried the following ?P<user>^[a-zA-Z]+\[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]....but can't get it to pass several email test codes? Thanks for all your help

Comment: @RobbieTrey hi, give me few moments will crack this up.